# join query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Here is my SQL query and result. My requirement is to display department_name with a maximum staff count but I don't know how to do that. 
I want a result like department_name - SE and staff_ count - 4 only.

```
    select d.department_name, count(staff_id) from department d, staff sf 
    where d.department_id = sf.staff_id
    group by department_name
    order by count(staff_id) desc
```

```
    DEPARTMENT_NAME                COUNT(SF.STAFF_ID)                               
    ------------------------------ ------------------                               
    SE                             4                               
    EEE                            2                               
    IT                             2                               
    CSE                            2                               
    ECE                            1
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking... please provide sample initial data, and expected results.

Comment: You can simply add ‘limit 1’ in the end of statement

Comment: LEFT Join to get entries for missing staff entries?

Comment: limit and top are not working in the compiler. please get another way to clear the business requirements

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful phrase to use to describe your results. If an error occurs, post the complete error message. If the results are not what you expected, post what was returned, what you expect, and some reasons for why you expect something different. And it is time to evolve - no one should be using old-style joins via the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

alias query

```
select d.department_name, count(staff_id)
from department d, staff sf 
where d.department_id = sf.staff_id AND d.department_name = 'SE'
group by department_name 
order by count(staff_id) desc
```

JOIN Query

```
select d.department_name, count(staff_id)
from department d 
INNER JOIN staff sf ON d.department_id = sf.staff_id
WHERE d.department_name = 'SE'
group by department_name 
order by count(staff_id) desc 
LIMIT 1
```

OR Top

```
select TOP 1 d.department_name, count(staff_id)
from department d 
INNER JOIN staff sf ON d.department_id = sf.staff_id
group by department_name 
order by count(staff_id) desc
```

Comment: It will clear the sample test case only. It won't clear all the test cases. please get another way

Comment: @Prabhu : If you want another test you put there test name in where clause

Comment: @Prabhu : Example - WHERE d.department_name = 'EEE'

Comment: @Prabhu : using TOP function

Comment: limit and top are not working in the compiler as per the business requirements

Answer (score 0):

You should use LIMIT 1 for reduce the result but also use explicit join syntax for a better readability:

```
select d.department_name, count(staff_id) 
from department d
INNER JOIN staff sf  ON  d.department_id = sf.staff_id
group by department_name
order by count(staff_id) desc
limit 1
```

Or without using limit you could try having on the max:

```
  select d.department_name, count(staff_id)  count_staff
  from department d
  INNER JOIN staff sf  ON  d.department_id = sf.staff_id
  group by department_name
  having count_staff = (
      select max(count_staff) 
      from ( select d.department_name, count(staff_id) count_staff
              from department d
               INNER JOIN staff sf  ON  d.department_id = sf.staff_id
                group by department_name ) t
  )
```

Comment: top and limit are not working in the compiler as per the business requirements

Comment: can you try this in another way

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the count of each department and then select department with the maximum count. Therefore, you can use sub-query as following:

```
SELECT d_name, MAX (staff_cnt) 
FROM (SELECT d.department_name as d_name, count(staff_id) as staff_cnt 
      FROM department d, staff sf 
      WHERE d.department_id = sf.staff_id
      GROUP BY department_name);
```

Comment: the error occurred like not a single group function